# wishlist integration in joomla

Tags: joomla

I am somewhat of newbeeeee to the whole Joomla/Virtuemart world. I am trying to implement **"my wishlist"** module in my joomla 1.5.26 . I have searched in google also but its not free.

My logic is like:

I have a list of products, along with button "**add to wish list**". If a registered user click on that button then that product id and category id have been saved in `jos_user` table, where I have added one new field called "**wishlist**".

Now up to this is okay. Now problem is to fetch those product in one page(lets say page name is my wish list), which are only in that list. Is there any file where I can change the query for that particular  page(my wish list). If so please help me. Its urgent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your wish list is a module rather than a component, then finding the required file to change the code shouldn't be too hard. I'm not quite sure on the file structure, but it will most likely be in something like helper.php

Comment: but its not a module but a component.

Comment: in which case, it will be in either the model or controller file

Comment: Actually I have made some changes in the following file:
"/components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/browse/browse_3.php" and keep the above logic.